# Executing PHP script with Cron doesn't have effect

Tags: php, cron

I'm using Cron to run a script every minute.
My `cron.php` is located in
`/var/www/test.com/public_html/cryptointerface/cron.php`.

Using Crontab (`crontab -e`) I defined the setup as:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/test.com/public_html/cryptointerface/cron.php
```

I let the cursor in an empty line right after this one.
After saving I got the message: `installing new crontab`.

The problem is that although *syslog* suggests that Cron is executing, it does not have the supposed effect. `cron.php` contains very basic code for writing something to file.

There is something that I'm missing, however I don't know what. All this is in a Ubuntu server.

Comment: Please paste script itself as that's what is not working.

Comment: change your cron to this `* * * * * cd /var/www/test.com/public_html/cryptointerface/ && /usr/bin/php cron.php` and let us know if it works.

Comment: Worked perfectly good job.